# Run npm build with specific .env file

Tags: reactjs

I have a react application that connect to micro services. I have different micro services urls per environment. I therefore have multiple env files: .env, .env-develoment-local, env-development,...

When I start the app locally, the app pick up the setting in the .env.development-local which is expecetd.

When I do npm run build I noticed that since it creating a production build, it picks up the .env file.

My question is how can configure the build such a way that it picks other .env files like .env.development or .env.qa, etc... ?

Comment: I am currently using dotenv but I don't know how to build with environment specific .env file. npm run build takes .env build default and I would like to be able to build with say .env.development or .env.qa,...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to get this working using https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd

I did the following:

```
npm install --save-dev env-cmd
```

Then updated package.json accordingly:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject",
   "build:stage": "env-cmd -f ./.env.stage npm run-script build" 
}
```

Then run the following command:

```
npm run build:stage
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Just in case, the "-f" option is very important and it means that we want to specify a custom env file name. Without it, the lib  uses a default file ".env".

Comment: You don't even need to update package.json file. Just running `env-cmd -f .env.stage yarn build` works fine.